# How to remove the "enable editing" banner in Foxit?

Tags: pdf, user-interface, write-protect

I want to read a PDF/A document in Foxit. I love reading in "fit page" zoom, and so I insist on maximizing screen space vertically, as missing vertical pixels result in a smaller rendering of the main page.

The document has an "enable editing" banner. It stays there even after switching to the reading view.

I don't want to enable editing. How do I get the banner to go away while the document stays write-protected?

[image: screenshot of the banner]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit -> Preferences (Ctrl+K) -> Documents. Under PDF/A View mode select Never. OK.